# Class to store data

Tags: c#, forms, class, variables

I'm writing a program in C# and I have a little problem with passing variable between two forms. For example in form1 I have got textbox where I put some data and I need to show it in textbox in form2. I tried to make additional class with properties "get,set" but it doesn't work, don't know why.

Code from form1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DaneDelegacja Dane = new DaneDelegacja();
            Dane.MiejsceDocelowe = textBox1.Text;

            // Create a new instance of the Form2 class
            Form2 settingsForm = new Form2();

            // Show the settings form
            settingsForm.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
```

and code from form2:

```
 public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DaneDelegacja Dane = new DaneDelegacja();
            textBox1.Text = Dane.MiejsceDocelowe;

        }
```

class to store data:

```
class DaneDelegacja
    {
        public  string MiejsceDocelowe { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not working because you are creating new instance every time in Form2's constructor.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DaneDelegacja Dane = new DaneDelegacja();
    Dane.MiejsceDocelowe = textBox1.Text;

    // Create a new instance of the Form2 class
    Form2 settingsForm = new Form2(Dane);

    // Show the settings form
    settingsForm.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

and code in form2:

```
public Form2(DaneDelegacja Dane)
{
    InitializeComponent();
   // DaneDelegacja Dane = new DaneDelegacja(); <-- remove this line
    textBox1.Text = Dane.MiejsceDocelowe;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your DaneDelegacja object you created in Form1 to Form1. At the moment you create a new object in Form2 which cannot have its property set.

```
public Form2(DaneDelegacja Dane)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.Text = Dane.MiejsceDocelowe;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data via Form2 constructor:

Code from form1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {             
            // Create a new instance of the Form2 class
            Form2 settingsForm = new Form2(textBox1.Text);

            // Show the settings form
            settingsForm.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
```

and code from form2:

```
 public Form2(string data)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            textBox1.Text = data;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an instance of the class.  See example below
Form1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 form2;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            form2 = new Form2(this);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form2.Show();
            string results = form2.GetData();
        }
    }
}
```

Form 2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Form1 form1;
        public Form2(Form1 nform1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Form2_FormClosing);
            form1 = nform1;
            form1.Hide();
        }
        private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            //stops for from closing
            e.Cancel = true;
            this.Hide();
        }
        public string GetData()
        {
            return "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
        }

    }
}
```